# How to download an rpm file using CURL?

Tags: curl

I'm using centos 6.9 and ubuntu 16, and trying to download an rpm file using curl command but unable to download in Centos but its working on Ubuntu.

Terminal Output ::
Ubuntu :

curl -O https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql80-community-release-el6-1.noarch.rpm

ubuntu:/tmp/rpms$ ls

mysql80-community-release-el6-1.noarch.rpm

When I tried the same command on CentOS it is not working.. Please Help!

[root@localContainer-MyLab55 ~]# curl -O https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql80-community-release-el6-1.noarch.rpm

[root@localContainer-MyLab55 ~]# ls

anaconda-ks.cfg  install.log  install.log.syslog

Comment: I can see that this question is being down voted, but I request before you down vote are you sure can you confirm it works on Centos?

Comment: best guess is that for some reason you can't see stderr output.. but what happens if you add `-v` to curl?

Comment: Thanks Hanshenrik I tried verbose but found no clues,
Here's my terminal output 

~]# curl -v https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql80-community-release-el6-1.noarch.rpm
* About to connect() to dev.mysql.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 137.254.60.11... connected
* Connected to dev.mysql.com (137.254.60.11) port 443 (#0)
.
*> GET /get/mysql80-community-release-el6-1.noarch.rpm HTTP/1.1
> Host: dev.mysql.com
> Accept: */*
< Location: https://repo.mysql.com//mysql80-community-release-el6-1.noarch.rpm
.
* Connection #0 to host dev.mysql.com left intact
* Closing connection #0

Comment: that is a [HTTP Location Redirect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections) which curl doesn't follow by default, but your browser does. to explicitly tell curl to follow Location-redirects, try: `curl -v -L url` , what do you get now?

Answer (score 10):

Thank you so much Hanshenrik for the support.. below command worked for me.

```
[root@localContainer-MyLab55 ~]# curl -v -O https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql80-community-release-el6-1.noarch.rpm -L 
[root@localContainer-MyLab55 ~]# ls
anaconda-ks.cfg  install.log  install.log.syslog  mysql80-community-release-el6-1.noarch.rpm
```